# D3.js: Scale for circle radius is not displaying the circles

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have created two scales for the x and y and both are working. Now when I try to do the same with the radius of the circles it doesn't show them, and it doesn't throw any error either.....What could be the problem. The codepen is the following: http://codepen.io/juanf03/pen/rrKxgd

```
   var
     dataset = [
                      [ 5,     20 ],
                      [ 480,   90 ],
                      [ 250,   50 ],
                      [ 100,   33 ],
                      [ 330,   95 ],
                      [ 410,   12 ],
                      [ 475,   44 ],
                      [ 25,    67 ],
                      [ 85,    21 ],
                      [ 220,   88 ]
                  ];
    var h=300,w=500;
    var padding = 20;
    var
     xScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, d3.max(dataset, 
    function(d) { return  d[0]; })]).range([padding, w-padding*2]);

    var yScale= d3.scaleLinear()
                .domain([0,d3.max(dataset,function(d){
                  return d[1];
                })]).range([h-padding,padding]);

    var
     rScale = d3.scaleLinear()                     .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, 
    function(d) { 
    return
     d[1]; })]).range([2, 5]);

    var svg=d3.select("body")
              .append("svg")
              .attr("width",w)
              .attr("height",h);

    svg.selectAll("circle")
       .data(dataset)
       .enter()
       .append("circle")
       .attr("cx",function(d){
        return xScale(d[0]);
      }).attr("cy",function(d){
        return yScale(d[1]);
      }).attr("r",function(d,i){
        return rScale(d[1]);
      });

    svg.selectAll("text")
       .data(dataset)
       .enter()
       .append("text")
       .text(function(d){
       return `${d[0]} , ${d[1]}`;
    }) .attr("x", function(d) {
    return xScale(d[0]);})
    .attr("y", function(d) {
    return yScale(d[1]);})
    .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
    .attr("font-size","11px")
    .attr("fill","red");


var
 xAxis = d3.svg.axis()                  .scale(xScale)                .orient("bottom");

svg.append("g")
    .call(xAxis);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspect your console: you have a lot of `NaN`. And they come from your `rScale`.

This is the problem: in JavaScript, a return statement followed by a line break tells the browser that a semi colon should be inserted after that return. So, when you write:

```
var rScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
        return 
            d[1]; })])
    .range([2, 5]);
```

You are actually writing:

```
return;
    d[1];
```

I did only one thing: just deleted the new line:

```
return d[1];
```

Here is your codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yaEwZW?editors=1010

Comment: your code seems to work perfectly. But the x axis is still not showing for some reason. I forgot to mention that....

Comment: That's a *different* problem. Here in SO we deal with one problem at a time, and one problem per question. I suggest you to post another question.